# Get partial tree() of a gremlin query

Tags: azure, graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am running this Gremlin query agains a Cosmos DB database. Which returns every persons 'p' for whom there exists a friend 'f' and including the friend 'f'

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('p')
     .out('friends').as('f')
     .select('f')
     .optional(outE()).tree()
```

Actual result is something like

```
{ p1: { f1, .. }, p2: { f1, ... } }
```

But how can I get only the friends 'f' and optional edges of 'f'? something like this:

```
{ f1, f2, ... }
```

*Portion of the actual result in GraphSON format:*

```
{
  "3": {
    "key": {"id": "1",...},
    "value": {
      "2": {
        "key": {
          "id": "2",
          "label": "person",
          "type": "vertex"
        },
        "value": { ... }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "key": {"id": "1", ... },
    "value": {
      "2": {
        "key": {
          "id": "2",
          "label": "person",
          "type": "vertex"
        },
        "value": {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unfold()` the tree result and select the values. This way you can get rid of the root nodes.

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').
  out('friends').
  optional(outE()).tree().
  unfold().
  select(values)
```

Comment: Although this is the answer to my question, this made me realize what I am actually was looking for, namely the 'vertex' including it's edges so I ended up using .union(identity(), outE()) instead of .tree()

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question based on what I learned about gremlin so far, the `GraphSONMode.Normal` does the trick.

Although this is the only way I found so far that also works in case of queries having nested / complex projections ( e.g. `project('parent').by(project('member').by(...))`), only deficiency is that it returns both incomming and outgoing adjancy list where I only need the outgoing edges.

I posted a suggestion to uservoice to have fine-grained control on the output format of the gremlin query and if you like to follow along please visit this link: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/32738743-add-more-options-for-graphsonmode